# Unable to request permission to access the IOS Calendar in Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, xcode10, ios12

I have tried the earlier examples of asking permission to add items to the IOS calendar.  They do not work with Xcode 10.1 (Swift 4.2).  When I try to compile the code, I get an error.  If I comment out the lines beginning with "EKEventstore.requestAccess", the code executes the ".not.Determined" loop.

The error is "Instance member 'requestAccess' cannot be used on type 'EKEventStore'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?"

Can anyone please find my error so that the IOS app can have permission to add events to the Calendar?

```
func SOGetPermissionCalendarAccess() {

    switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event) {

    case .authorized:
        print("Authorized")

    case .denied:
        print("Access denied")

    case .notDetermined:
        EKEventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion:
            {[weak self] (granted: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in
                if granted {
                    print("Access granted")
                } else {
                    print("Access denied")
                }
        })

        print("Not Determined")
    default:
        print("Case Default")
        }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

You should create event store instance as like below,

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
```

After that you can make permission request as like below,

```
switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event) {

        case .authorized:
            print("Authorized")

        case .denied:
            print("Access denied")

        case .notDetermined:
            eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion:
                {(granted: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in
                    if granted {
                        print("Access granted")
                    } else {
                        print("Access denied")
                    }
            })

            print("Not Determined")
        default:
            print("Case Default")
        }
```

Please refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore) for more info.

Comment: This worked.  The line after "eventStore.." should be

"  {(granted: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in"

because self is not used.

Comment: Yeah correct. If you didn't use "self" inside that completion block, you can remove that part.

Comment: Is is somehow possible to programatically change authorization denied by user in macOS settings? Or reset app authorization to status .notDetermined?

Answer (score 0):

Apple documentation for EKEventStore is to execute [reset()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507345-reset) method, that does not help either.
My workaround is to initialise the EKEventStore once again, after requestAccess method.

```
private var store: EKEventStore
private var calendars: [EKCalendar] = []

private func requestAccessCalendars() {
    store.requestAccess(to: .event) { [weak self] (accessGranted, error) in
        if accessGranted {
            self?.store = EKEventStore() // <- second instance
            self?.store.refreshSourcesIfNecessary()

            self?.loadCalendars()
        }
    }
}

private func loadCalendars() {
    let cals = store.calendars(for: .event)
    for c in cals {
        if c.allowsContentModifications { // without birthdays, holidays etc'...
            calendars.append(c)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With **iOS17**, the **request(to:, completion:)** method is deprecated with **requestFullAccessToEvents(completion:)** and **requestWriteOnlyAccessToEvents(completion:)** .

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/4162272-requestfullaccesstoevents

So updated version for request might be as following;

```
switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event) {
    case .fullAccess:
        print("Full Access")
    case .authorized:
        print("Authorized")
    case .writeOnly:
        print("Write Only Access")
    case .denied:
        print("Authorization Denied")
    case .notDetermined:
        if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
            eventStore.requestFullAccessToEvents { isGranted, error in
                print("isGranted: ", isGranted)
            }
        } else {
            eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { isGranted, error in
                print("isGranted: ", isGranted)
            }
        }
    default:
        print("Default Case")
}
```